# What is a one-sigma Ellipse?

Tags: probability

What is a 1-Signa ellipse? What does it represent?
Also, I read the following sentence "One-Sigma lines of equal probability density of two normal distributions [(n^2 + n)/2 free parameters]"

Why are the ellipses different in the image although the sigma lines are for equal probabilities?

Sorry, but I am not statistician.

[image]

Comment: Equal probability density is along the same distribution. But here you have two (different) distributions! 
Pick one ellipse. The points on the perimeter have all equal probability density. The points inside have larger probability density, the points outside smaller. Look "bivariate Gaussian" on Google images, you will see a graph of the distribution. The ellipse is simply a horizontal section of that graph.

Comment: Thanks @geodude, but what is 1-Sigma ellipse? As far as I understand, it is a special ellipse of the distribution, but which one, and why is it important?
I found this article, but I didn't understand it:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/39311

Comment: The linked article is no longer accessible.

Answer (score 1):

The points along the solid-line ellipse all have the same probability density as each other according to a normal distribution $f.$

The points along the broken-line ellipse all have the same probability density as each other according to a normal distribution $g.$

There is nothing in the quoted passage that says the two distributions are the same. In fact it is rather strongly hinted that they are different.
The fact that we have two ellipses confirms that they *are* different.

There is also nothing in the quoted passage that says the probability density along the solid-line ellipse over $f$ is the same as the probability density along the broken-line ellipse over $g.$

In particular, where the two ellipses intersect, you have a point that may have a different probability density according to distribution $f$ than according to distribution $g.$

Granted, this is using a bit of reasoning about how probability works (and about how normal distributions work) in order to navigate the ambiguities of the English language. Sometimes you have to think a little about the possible meanings in order to make sense of things. The interpretation that makes sense is that it is not the two curves that are "equal" to each other, but rather the density along one of those curves is "equal" to itself.